# When does an c/c++ project need a configure file?

Tags: c++, c, configure

Almost every c/c++ open source project I see ships with it a `configure` file.

But in our own c/c++ project I haven't seen this file so far,

when is it needed?

Comment: Maybe it contains CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: I think no. CMakeLists.txt is used for cmake build system. `configure` file is typically used by `autotools`.

Comment: @Begemoth ,no,there's only `Makefile`..

Comment: Highly recommend to read the easy to digest Wikipedia article about autotools. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Autotools

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are speaking about configure script which is used, when [autotools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system) are used to build the project.

The main purpose of the `configure` file is to generate `Makefiles` appropriate to your system configuration and to check various preconditions (installed libs, for example).

Comment: when do we need to check the preconditions,can we detect it at run time when necessary?

Comment: Let's say a particular compiler is available on one OS and a different one is available on a different OS. The command to build your program (and hence the makefile) will have to be different for each OS. The job of the configure file is to detect such differences and generate appropriate makefiles for your system.

Comment: @wireshark: also it can check whether you have appropriate libs installed on your system (to prevent getting compile or link error later), get some system information if needed (hostname, version, etc.), find the path to a particular executables (lex, for example), check if some used tools supports particular options.

Answer (score 7):

A `configure` script is the penultimate step in building a project that uses [GNU autotools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system). Autotools is a set of tools that has been designed to maximize portability of an application between various POSIX and POSIX-like operating environments which may have slightly different features outside the base set which the application needs.

TL;DR: `configure` matters when you want portability between many different OSes.

Comment: can you give a tiny example that shows how `configure` can make portable?

Comment: `configure` on its own cannot. The tools that generate it, as well as the template files used by those tools, are what make the application portable.

Comment: When could I find a Minimal, Reproducible Example of a small project using `configure` to undersand better how it works?

Answer (score 3):

When it gets too complex for you to create the Makefile by hand.

Comment: That is the job of the Automake and CMake, not autoconf.

Answer (score 2):

A `configure` script serves basically three purposes:

1. Detecting availability (or user preference) of optional libraries, or checking for the presence and the correct options needed for making use of mandatory libraries your program depends on.
2. Working around broken operating systems where standard library functions are missing or don't behave as specified by the standards.
3. Working around broken non-portable assumptions in your program by detecting system parameters that you shouldn't have to care about and reporting them to your program.

Purpose 3 has always been useless for properly written code. There is no reason you need to know `sizeof(int)` at the preprocessor level, for instance. If you want a particular size, use a fixed-size integer type like `int32_t` (and as part of point 2, configure can patch around broken systems that are missing it). Likewise, you should not be writing programs whose behavior depends on whether `malloc(0)` returns `NULL` or a "unique pointer that can be passed successfully to `free`". (Yes, there is plenty of broken software that actually cares!)

Purpose 2 was historically very important to the way GNU versions of the basic system software became so ubiquitous, by supporting a huge spectrum of proprietary Unices with broken compilers and libraries, and delivering better quality than the native tools could typically offer. Nowadays, every single Unix-like system has build and runtime environments that are either fully or almost POSIX compliant, and you can obtain them by with `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=(version goes here)` and possibly some additions to `$PATH` for the shell stuff. As such, purpose 2 is generally obsolete and harmful now unless you're trying to support non-POSIX systems like Windows (without cygwin).

Purpose 1 is still very relevant, and not going away anytime soon.

Some projects, arguably for very good reason, do not like GNU autotools and refuse to use any of it, either omitting `configure` or rolling their own. If you only need `configure` for the first purpose, this approach *may* make sense, if you understand all the potential troubles and know how to write portable shell script. If you do this, however, please be sure to learn and follow all of the `configure` conventions for how options (like `--enable-*`, `--prefix`, etc.) and variables (`CFLAGS`, `CPPFLAGS`, etc.) work so you don't create a nightmare for users. And keep in mind using autoconf may just be easier and worth doing - but please avoid wasting everyone's time having it check stupid things like `sizeof(int)` or whether for Fortran compiler works.

Answer (score 0):

configure is generated by autoconf, from the GNU Autotools. You can use autoconf and automake to manage the build system for your project; if you don't want to or can't rely on your IDE being present, autotools are another way to manage building and installing your code. OS portability is another major thing they help with, though mainly between different UNIX-based systems, which isn't as much of a problem anymore.

More succinctly, if you get tired of manually editing Makefiles or need to break out of your IDE, consider using Autotools or one of its alternatives, like CMake or SCons.